# How can I temporarily disable an animation?

Tags: animation, smoke-simulation

I have this file with an animation in it. Now I added a smoke simulation. But every time I play the smoke simulation also the animation starts running. How prevent this ? In fact I would like to make the animation "inactive" but not delete it. How to do that ?

Comment: Go to the dopesheet and move the keyframes of your animation to the point where you want it  to start.

Comment: That is the point .... I want the animation (the earth turing arounds its axis) to be inactive (so not playing at all) when I click ALT + A, I want just only the smoke simulation to run. Like you can restrict Viewport Visibility or restrict rendering for an object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

In all 3 windows

- Graph editor Window
- Dope Sheet Window
- NLA Edit Window

... it is possible to toggle the mute button of the channel transformation.  Contribution can be active or inactive.

Thus if the timeline were on frame 88 and the sphere was animated to rotate and the Blender User decided to disable the contribution of the channe .... then the sphere would no longer rotate dynamically and it would be frozen at the rotation of frame 88.  Later the contribution can be turned on again.  Blender uses the word mute so I am partially conforming to that jargon.

[image]

Image above. [Contribution/No Contribution] or Mute button has the shape of a speaker.  Speaker has no sound marks. Contribution inactive.

[image]

Image above. Speaker has sound marks.  Contribution active.

Comment: do you mean Alt + W ?? Disable Channel and then Mute ? I tried that at frame 0 but I don't think it works

Comment: What I explained above was tested today.  Functions as documented for the example.

Comment: Cool !! Exactly what I was looking for !! Thanks